# avoiding modification of hidden variable data in Perl/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, perl

In my application using hidden variables to store data and using method POST to call a function and wanted to preserve data modification from users.
Since hidden variables are visible in the HTML that the server sends to the browser; all a user has to do is view the source of the document. After that, the user can set the hidden variables to his/her desire and send it back to the script.

Please let me know how can i avoid modification of data in hidden fields. Since while performing auditing, raised a issues as unhandled exception. let me know how to overcome this issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a unique token to check the integrity of hidden values available to the client side. Here's one attempt to solve this problem:

> 1. Generate unique token
> 2. Store unique token and hidden values in the database
> 3. Render page with unique token and hidden values
> 4. Process post data with unique token and hidden values
> 5. Compare database values with user submitted data (integrity check)
> 6. Expire unique token (delete row)

Comment: There is no need to transmit the data itself if it is also being stored server-side. Just a unique token without a value will suffice

Comment: @Borodin - that's also possible since you can get the hidden values via the unique token. Thanks!